# Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I want to store some data into database through `OnetoMany` and `ManytoOne` Bidirectional relationship mapping. While request for persist data in postman get infinite row in response.

Here down is my code:

**Entity**

```
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer author_id;
    private String name;
    private String language;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "author")
    private Set<Book> book;

    // getter setter
}

public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;

    // getter setter
}
```

**Service**

```
@Override
public Author insertAuthor(Author author) {
        Set<Book> bookList = new HashSet<>();
        
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setTitle(book.getTitle());
        
        bookList.add(book);
        
        book.setAuthor(author);
        author.setBook(bookList);
        
        return authorRepo.save(author);
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class PojoController {
    
    @Autowired
    private PojoService pojoService;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/book", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Author addBookCourse(@RequestBody Author author) {
        return this.pojoService.insertAuthor(author);
    }
}
```

**Request**

```
{
    "language": "english",
    "name": "Banjamin franklin",
    "book": [{
        "title": "Theory Of Everything"
    },
    {
        "title": "A Brief Story Of Time"
    }]
}
```

**Output**

```
{
    "author_id": 1,
    "name": "Banjamin franklin",
    "language": "english",
    "book": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": null,
            "author": {
                "author_id": 1,
                "name": "Banjamin franklin",
                "language": "english",
                "book": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "title": null,
                        "author": {
                            "author_id": 1,
                            "name": "Banjamin franklin",
                            "language": "english",
                            "book": [
                                {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "title": null,
                                    "author": {
                                        "author_id": 1,
                                        "name": "Banjamin franklin",
                                        "language": "english",
                                        "book": [
                                            {
                                                "id": 1,
                                                "title": null,
                           more 7460 line
                           .......
                           .......
                           .......
{
    "timestamp": "2021-11-30T10:25:03.957+00:00",
    "status": 200,
    "error": "OK",
    "trace": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.rest.RestApiPojo.Entity.Author[\"book\"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->com.rest.RestApiPojo.Entity.Book[\"author\"]->com.rest.RestApiPojo.Entity.Author[\"book\"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->com.rest.RestApiPojo.Entity.Book[\"author\"]
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to use DTOs instead of working directly with your entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` to allow Jackson to better handle the relationship between `Author` and `Book`:

```java
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer author_id;
    private String name;
    private String language;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "author")
    private Set<Book> book;

    // getter setter
}
```

```java
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String title;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;

    // getter setter
}
```

You have other options (e.g. using `@JsonIdentityInfo`) to handle this infinite recursion issue, but this is the most common solution. You can check all other possible approaches at the following online resource https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion.

---

Additionally, in your Service you are creating a brand new `Book` and setting its title with `book.setTitle(book.getTitle());`, which basically does nothing. In fact you don't even need to do most of the stuff you are doing there because `Book` instances are already in `Author`, you just need to set `Author` on each `Book` instance as follows:

```java
@Override
public Author insertAuthor(Author author) {
    for (Book book : author.getBook()) {
        book.setAuthor(author);
    }
    
    return authorRepo.save(author);
}
```

Finally, consider changing the `book` property in `Author` to `books` since it contains multiple books (you will need to adjust your code afterwards).

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej please check my updated answer. You also need to change your Service ;)

Comment: thanks solved and your answer is more usefull